# Reference request: structure of group of units of finite group ring

Tags: reference-request, ra.rings-and-algebras, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a **finite** group, let $F$ be a **finite** field and let $F[G]$ be the group algebra of $G$ over $F$.

1. What is known about the structure of the group of units $F[G]^\times$? Of course, it must contain a subgroup isomorphic to $G$.
2. Is there anything special about how $G$ is embedded in $F[G]^\times$?

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/142899/units-in-a-group-algebra To put it simply: for your first question, answer is "something is known, but not much". For your second one — I'd say that finding the *right way* to ask it would be a major breakthrough in modular representation theory.